# How to remove memory location that is referenced objects in python?

Tags: python, reference, weak-references

I want to remove all objects, which refer to one memory location. How to do it if I do not know their all name?

```python
class Foo(object):
    pass


class Bar(object):
    pass

a = Foo()
b = a
c = Bar()
c.a_ref = a
c.b_ref = b

for item in a, b, c.a_ref, c.b_ref:
    print(id(item))

""" Out:
140035270075472
140035270075472
140035270075472
140035270075472
"""
```

**UPD:**

Ok. I want to remove `link` or `port1.link` and don't worry about all the other ports(`port2.link`) linked to it, they also have to disappear.

```python
class LINK(object):
    pass


class PORT(object):

    def __init__(self, link=None):
        self.link = link

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(id(self.link))

link = LINK()

port1 = PORT()
port2 = PORT()
port1.link = port2.link = link

print(id(link), port1, port2)
# (140586778512720, 140586778512720, 140586778512720)
del link
print(port1, port2)
# (140586778512720, 140586778512720)
# want: (None, None) ???
```

Comment: Why? What is your real problem?

Comment: I'm a little updated example, maybe it can be done differently, but I think that the idea of delete memory location, is the logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/weakref.html#module-weakref) module.  It maintains a reference to an object without preventing it from being garbage collected if all its strong references are removed.  Example:

```
import weakref

class LINK(object):
    pass

class PORT(object):

    def __init__(self, link=None):
        if link is not None:
            self.link = weakref.ref(link)
        else:
            self.link = None

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.link is None:
            return 'None'
        o = self.link()
        return 'None' if o is None else str(id(o))

link = LINK()

port1 = PORT()
port2 = PORT()
port1.link = port2.link = weakref.ref(link)

print(id(link), port1, port2)
del link
print(port1, port2)
```

Output:

```
70741240 70741240 70741240
None None
```

Note, you may still have to call `gc.collect()` in some situations before the weak references report `None`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I expected. But the other answers are also useful for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can't explicitly free memory in Python. The garbage collector is responsible to do that for you.

What you can do is guarantee that all the references to your objects are cleaned. The garbage collector works with epochs (like e1, e2 and e3) and only the objects in e3 will be cleaned in the next iteration.

Objects only go from epoch eX to eY (where Y > X) if there is no reference to them. So your objects start in e1; if you "clean" all references, in the next iteration of garbage collector they will be moved to e2; in the next one they will be moved to e3 and finally the memory will be released.

You can change the periodicity that garbage collector is called, but I would not recommend that. Or you can force the calling of garbage collector using `gc.collect()` but as I said, your objects have to go through all epochs before they are cleaned (that's why the calling of `gc.collector()` didn't work for you). Just to clarify, the garbage collector is called once a threshold (number of objects in memory tracked by the gc) is achieved.

If you want to do a diagnoses of memory leaks in Python you can also use the `objgraph` library which is really good. It builds graphs with all links and references between objects and let you identify cycles. Cycles are the main reason for the objects not to be released by the garbage collector when you think that all references are cleaned. Here is a good tutorial http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicitly free memory. What you need to do is to make sure you don't keep references to objects. They will then be garbage collected, freeing the memory.
BTW, you can call `gc.collect()` to force a gc operation.

**UPDATE:**

You CAN NOT delete all the references to one object through only deleting one of its references, since you don't know who else is still using this object. And if so, there will be another question, how to prevent others to delete my object without acknowledging me.

I think best solution to your question is to delete attribute link separately.

```
del link
del port1.link
del port2.link
```

Then to get None after deleting, you should do this:

```
...
def __repr__(self):
        repr_string = getattr(self, 'link', None)
        return str(id(self.link)) if repr_string else None
...
```

Comment: see UPD: please, ``gc.collect`` not solve my problem

Comment: Yes, but how do I get all linked objects, if they may change?

Comment: @uralbash No way. The only way to prevent others from using your object is to give it a private name, like self.__my_private_name, to tell others 'please don't use this object, it is only for private use'. Then you can delete it whenever you like.

Comment: Even deleting the attributes it is not guaranteed that the memory will be released.

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem, to me, sounds like you have a graph where `PORT`s are nodes and `LINK`s are edges. And your requirement is that when you delete an edge, the two nodes that the edge connects should also be deleted. This can be done explicitly by overriding the `__del__` method of the node so that deleting it deletes the edges which is connects to.

Python abstracts away the "memory" and using the fact that `id` gives you the memory location (which is really an implementation detail of CPython) is a flaky way of doing this.